# Recorrer una diagonal

Tags: javascript

estoy acabando el conecta 4 en javaScript, sólo me falta que me confirme si he ganado si lo recorro diagonalmente pero no se me ocurre (en vertical y horizontal ya lo tengo). ¿Podríais echarme una mano?

Tengo la celda seleccionada, pero no sé luego como recorrerla, he probado a recorrer con un FOR pero tampoco acaba de funcionar ni nada. Entonces era pasa saber si me podiais echar una mano.  Sé que el codigo no es perfecto, estoy aún aprendiendo. Gracias!!

```
function ultimaFilaPintada(arrayCeldas){
    for(fila=arrayCeldas.length-1; fila>0; fila--){
        if (!arrayCeldas[fila].classList.contains("jugador1") && !arrayCeldas[fila].classList.contains("jugador2") ){
            return fila;
        }
   }
}



function buscarColumna(){
    let c4 = document.getElementById("conectaCuatro");
    let tr = c4.children[0].children;
    for (let fila=0; fila<8; fila++){
        for (let columna=0; columna<7; columna++){
            let celda = tr[fila].children[columna];
            if (celda.classList.contains("seleccionado")) { 
                celda.classList.remove("seleccionado");
                arrayCeldas = [];
                // Ahora que ya hemos encontrado la celda seleccionada, sabemos en que columna estamos
                // Recorremos lasa filas de esa columna par poder sacar en un array todas las celdas
                // que pertenecen a esa columna
                for(let i=0; i<8; i++){
                    let celdasQuePertenecenAColumnaSeleccionada = tr[i].children[columna]
                    arrayCeldas.push(celdasQuePertenecenAColumnaSeleccionada);
                }
                return [arrayCeldas,columna]
            }   
        }
    }
}




function ganadorDiagonal(indiceUltimaFilaPintada, columnaSeleccionada){
    let tablaJuego = document.getElementById("conectaCuatro");
    let tr = tablaJuego.children[0].children;
    let diagonalIzquierda= tr[indiceUltimaFilaPintada-1].children[columnaSeleccionada-1];
    

    if (indiceUltimaFilaPintada>=columnaSeleccionada){
        let diagonalFila = indiceUltimaFilaPintada - columnaSeleccionada;
        console.log("-----" + diagonalFila);
            for (let i=0; i<diagonalFila; i++){
            console.log("vale i " + i);
                    
            }

        puntuacionJ1 = 0;
        puntuacionJ2 = 0;
    }       
    // else {
    //     let diagonalColumna = columnaSeleccionada - indiceUltimaFilaPintada;
    //     console.log("*****" + diagonalColumna);
    // }

    // if (indiceUltimaFilaPintada+columnaSeleccionada===7){
    //     console.log("pinto correcto +7");
    // }
    // else if (indiceUltimaFilaPintada+columnaSeleccionada===8){
    //     console.log("pinto correcto +8");
    // }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que partimos de la siguiente matriz:

```js
let a = 1; let b = 2;
let matriz = [
    [ 0, 0, 0, b, b, a ], [ a, a, b, b, a, a ],
    [ a, a, b, b, b, a ], [ a, b, b, a, b, a ],
    [ b, a, a, b, b, b ], [ b, b, a, b, a, a ]
]

function devolverDiagonales( matriz, dir ) {
    let inicioCol = matriz[ 0 ].length - 2;
    let finCol = matriz[ 0 ].length - 1;
    let finRow = matriz.length - 1;
    let col = matriz[ 0 ].length - 2;
    let salto = false;
    let inicioRow = 0;
    let row = 0;
    let sum = 1;
    let aux = [];
    let salida = [];
    
   while( true ) {
      aux.push( matriz[ row ][ col ] );
      if( row == finRow && salto ) {
         salida.push( aux );
         aux = [];
         if( col == 1 ) {
            return salida;
         }
         inicioRow++;
         col = -1;
         row = inicioRow - 1;
      }
      if( col == finCol ) {
         salida.push( aux );
         aux = [];
         inicioCol--;
         col = inicioCol;
         if( row == finRow ) {
            inicioRow++;
            inicioCol = 0;
            col = 0;
            salto = true;
         }
         row = inicioRow;
      }
      else {
         row += sum;
         col += sum;
      }
   }
}

console.log( devolverDiagonales( matriz, "der" ));
```

Solo con ocho meses de atraso, llega mi respuesta.
Esta función, devuelve una lista de listas, cada una de las cuales, tiene los valores de una diagonal (solo para las diagonales derechas).
La ejecución empieza por la primer fila y la ante última columna.
Entrada en el `while`, se carga en el `array` **`aux`** el contenido de la casilla correspondiente.
En la primera mitad de la ejecución, no puede entrar al primer `if`, porque **`salto`** es `false`.
En el bloque `if/else if`, entra en el `else`, aumenta el valor de **`row`** y de **`col`**.
Cuando **`col`** llega a `5` (en nuestro ejemplo), entra en el `if`, carga en el array **`salida`**, el array **`aux`**, vacia este, baja en `1` el valor de **`inicioCol`** (para que en la próxima iteración, arranque desde la columna anterior), establece col con el valor de **`inicioCol`**, si **`row`** llega a su máximo, se aumenta el valor de **`inicioRow`** (para que empiece a buscar desde la siguiente fila), se le da a **`inicioCol`** y col el valor `0`, y se pasa salto a `true`, para que se pueda entrar en el primer `if`.
En el primer `if`, repetimos el proceso de cargar **`aux`** en **`salida`**, limpiar **`aux`**, luego verificamos si col es `1`, en cuyo caso retornamos **`salida`**, si no es así, aumentamos el valor de **`inicioRow`**, seteamos **`col`** en `-1` y **`row`** e **`inicioiRow`** en `-1`, tal vez llamen la atención estos valores, es que hay que tener en cuenta, que si o si, va a entrar en el else, que va a aumentar tanto **`col`** como **`row`**.